# Rails 'generate' command different app frameworks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Where can I find the list of different application frameworks created from the Rails 'generate' command?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure entirely what you mean by 'application framework' but you can see the entire list of generators available in your current environment by running `rails g -h`. (Or `rails generate --help` if you're not into the whole brevity thing.)

Comment: I thought when you ran the 'generate' command it would create different framework depending on what the application was to become?  I thought wrong...